# C Programming : Parameter : Can't convert to int*

Tags: c, arrays, merge

i am new here and i have a question.

I'm doing my C Programming Assignment about Procedure and Struct.

So i want to declare an Array of a Struct, and after that put it as an alias. Here is the code :

```
typedef struct Mahasiswa
{
    int NIM;    
    char NamaMhs[16];
    char KodeMK[6];
    char Nilai;
}TabMhs[100];
TabMhs M; //Alias
```

And i want to use this struct as a parameter of another procedure :

This is the procedure :

```
void SortDataMhs(struct Mahasiswa M[Nmaks],int n);
```

and this is the procedure call :

```
SortDataMhs(&M,n);
```

But i got an error : 
[Error] Cannot convert 'Mahasiswa(*)][100]' to 'Mahasiswa*' for argument '1' 'void SortDataMhs(Mahasiswa*,int)'

Any help? And sorry for asking such a newbie question. Because i am new to Programming :)

Comment: What do you mean by an "alias"? This is not a C term. I need to ask otherwise your intention is unclear and thus it would be difficult to answer.

Comment: I don't really know, i think it's like the actual variable is TabMhs but i use it to shorten the variable as M

Comment: Call `SortDataMhs` like this `SortDataMhs(M,n)` or `SortDataMhs(&M[0],n)`. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration of an array of structure, i.e.:

```
typedef struct Mahasiswa
{
    int NIM;    
    char NamaMhs[16];
    char KodeMK[6];
    char Nilai;
}TabMhs[100];
TabMhs M; //Alias
```

is not good practice. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8043760/6400614).

Now, the code below is more readable and understandable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Mahasiswa
{
    int NIM;    
    char NamaMhs[16];
    char KodeMK[6];
    char Nilai;
}TabMhs;

TabMhs m[100];

void ss(TabMhs* m, int n){ // `m` is the pointer to array of structures and `n` is the number of elements in that array.
    for(int i=0; i<n ; i++){
        printf("%d\t%s\t%s\t%c\t%d\n", m[i].NIM, m[i].NamaMhs, m[i].KodeMK, m[i].Nilai, n);
    }
}

int main(){
    m[0].NIM = 0;
    strcpy(m[0].NamaMhs, "m0nama");
    strcpy(m[0].KodeMK, "m0kod");
    m[0].Nilai='a';

    m[1].NIM = 1;
    strcpy(m[1].NamaMhs, "m1nama");
    strcpy(m[1].KodeMK, "m1kod");
    m[1].Nilai='b';

    ss(m,2);

    return 0;
}
```

But say tomorrow your array of structures need more (or less) than 100 elements, in that case, you can make that array dynamic by removing the statement TabMhs m[100] and replacing it with this:

```
int main(){

    int n = 10;
    TabMhs* m = malloc(sizeof(TabMhs) * n);

    /* rest of the code remains same */

    free(m);
}
```

Comment: Okay, i get it thank you so much for your long answer, i feel really thankful. But if i can ask more what does * after TabMhs after parameter of 'ss'?

Comment: A "*" means that the variable is a pointer. So, `m` is a pointer to a variable of type `TabMhs`. A "pointer" is just like any other variable, except it stores the "address" to another variable. I'd suggest you read about pointers in C: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/

Comment: Oh, it is the same if i put it as "TabMhs* M" and TabMhs *M"?

Comment: Yes, the spacing there doesn't matter. Even `TabMhs * M` is the same as the `TabMhs* M` and `TabMhs *M`.